# How to long tap to recognize as picture in mobile browser when using background-image in css?

Tags: html, css

I'm using `background-image` in css, when I long tap the image in mobile browser, normally it should popup to show "Save image to phone", but actually nothing happens.

My code is like below:

```
<style>
.bg {
    background-image: url("../images/boy1.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

I also tried with `<img src="xxx">`, this time when I long tap on the image, it will show "Save as picture". But I wonder if the same thing can happen with `background-image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's not possible. I create a dirty hack for this. I'm not recommending to use it if there's a right way to do it.

```js
$(".bg").contextmenu(function(){
 $(this).append("<img src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'/>");
});
```

```css
.bg {
    background-image: url("https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff");
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: relative;
}

.bg img {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bg"></div>
```

Comment: This works! Let's wait for some time see if there is an *official* way...

Comment: @zhm Sure, I've been searching for a right way to do it too but found none. Also I added a new tags such as javascript and jquery since it's a client-side work and to gain more help.